# Ionic4: give image-size as cover to background image url

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to give background image to ion-toolbar since the image goes too big, so I want to use `image-size: cover` for the background image so that it best fits in the ion-toolbar.

I tried to give in below format but it did not work, any idea how to make it work.

```
ion-toolbar {
    --background: url(assets/images/background/bg-header-flag.jpg) no-repeat cover;
    --min-height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally after struggling so long got the answer

```
    --background: url('assets/images/background/bg-header-flag.jpg') center/ cover no-repeat;
```

Below is the syntax of using short hand notation of background property.

```
background: bg-color bg-image position/bg-size bg-repeat bg-origin bg-clip bg-attachment initial|inherit;
```

For more details check https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can also refer the following link for Background-size property:

https://alligator.io/css/background-size-property/